# Remove "delivery-time-details" container from Template - produced by getPriceHtml

Tags: product-view

In the product View a function `getPriceHtml` displays the Product price, but it seems that apart form that it also displays the delivery-time-details. I can see it, since by removing this function call the delivery-time-details HTML container also disappears. 
But even in the `getPriceHtml` method definition in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` the delivery-time-details are not present.

Could someone tell me where to find the line, which prints the delivery-time-details after the price?

Answer (score 0):

You should look for it in layout's xml files. It can be added by some module, search for its name in files inside `app/design/frontend/.../.../layout`.

Another option is that this block is created programatically, using `getLayout()->createBlock()`. Look for it in your codebase.

Comment: I did, but there is nothing regarding the delivery or stock in the layout file of catalog...

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: *createBlock* is present in the **_getPriceBlock** method in the **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract** ... but it only calls the **catalog/product_price** block which doesn't contain any information on delivery